# Regular Expressions in C# kill program

Tags: c#, regex

I'm doing a program for a class, and when I run it and type something in the txtSSN control that's not valid, it freezes up and crashes. I can't figure it out because I have another very similar project that works just fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace VitalStatistics
{
    public partial class frmVitalStatistics : Form
    {
        #region Declarations

        const String AppTitle = "Vital Statistics";
        const float hoursOffset = 24.999F;

        Regex ssnRegex;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public frmVitalStatistics()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    #endregion

        #region Event Handlers

       private void frmVitalStatistics_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         // Initialize SSN input control
            RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
            string pattern = @"\A\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\Z";
            ssnRegex = new Regex(pattern, options);

         // Init. Gender controls
            optGender = Gender.Unassigned;

            rbFemale.Tag = Gender.Male;
            rbMale.Tag = Gender.Female;

         // Init dtpBirth controls
            dtpBirth.MinDate = DateTime.Today;
            dtpBirth.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hoursOffset);
            dtpBirth.Value = DateTime.Today;

        }

       private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string name = String.Empty;
            string ssn = String.Empty;
            int length = 0;
            int weight = 0;

            DateTime birthDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            Gender gender = Gender.Unassigned;

           //Gather inputs

           if (GetName(ref name) &&
               GetSSN(ref ssn) &&
               GetLength(ref length) &&
               GetWeight(ref weight) &&
               GetGender(ref gender) &&
               GetBirthDate(ref birthDate))
           {
               //submit & close
               string format = 
                   "Thank you for submitting your contact information. \n\n" +
                   "Name: {0}\n" +
                   "SSN: {1}\n" +
                   "Length: {2}\n" +
                   "Weight: {3}\n" +
                   "Gender: {4}\n" +
                   "Birth Date & Time: {5:D}\n";

               string msg = String.Format(format, name, ssn, length, weight, gender, birthDate);
               MessageBox.Show(msg,AppTitle);
               Close();
           }
       }



       private Gender optGender;
       private void Gender_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
           optGender = (rb.Checked ? (Gender)rb.Tag : Gender.Unassigned);
       }

        #endregion

        #region Implementation

        bool GetName(ref string name)
       {
           if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text))
           {
               txtName.SelectAll();
               txtName.Focus();
               ShowError("Please enter your name.\n Names cannot consist of whitespace.");

               return false;
           }

           name = txtName.Text.Trim();

           return true;
       }

        bool GetSSN(ref string ssn)
       {
           txtSSN.Text = txtSSN.Text.Trim();

           Match match = ssnRegex.Match(txtSSN.Text);

           if (!match.Success)
           {
               txtSSN.SelectAll();
               txtSSN.Focus();
               ShowError("Unrecognized format for SSN. Please enter in the following format: 000-000-0000.");
               return false;

           }

           ssn = txtSSN.Text;
           return true;
       }

        bool GetLength(ref int length)
       {
           int value;
           try
           {
               if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLength.Text))
                   throw new ArgumentException("Field cannot be empty or contain spaces.");

               value = int.Parse(txtLength.Text);

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               // Select text and set focus
               txtLength.SelectAll();
               txtLength.Focus();

               // Set up error Message
               string msg = String.Format("{0}", ex);

               ShowError(ex.Message);
               return false;
           }

           length = value;
           return true;
       }

        bool GetWeight(ref int weight)
        {
            int value;
            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtWeight.Text))
                    throw new ArgumentException("Field cannot be empty or contain spaces.");

                value = int.Parse(txtLength.Text);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Select text and set focus
                txtWeight.SelectAll();
                txtWeight.Focus();

                // Set up error Message
                string msg = String.Format("{0}", ex);

                ShowError(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }

            weight = value;
            return true;
        }

        bool GetGender(ref Gender gender)
        {
            if (optGender == Gender.Unassigned)
            {
                ShowError("Select a Gender.");
                return false;
            }
            gender = optGender;
            return true;
        }

        bool GetBirthDate(ref DateTime birthDate)
        {
           birthDate = dtpBirth.Value;
           return true;
        }

        void ShowError(string msg)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(msg, AppTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
        }

         #endregion



    }



}
```

Comment: just paste it on SO and indent 4 spaces...no sense making us click.

Comment: also, i dont even see a regular expression in here, but i suspect that's NOT your problem. regexes dont randomly crash programs. they might throw an exception if the regex is malformed though. the regex pattern isnt generated from user input, is it?

Comment: @Mark: I missed it on first look, `string pattern = @"\A\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\Z";` It's in there.

Comment: Under the frmVitalStatistics_Load event handler, I setup a new regex to verify the txtSSN is in a valid format, then under bool GetSSN method, I'm checking to see if it matches... I'm sorry if I'm way off I'm doing my best.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?  Why post that huge block and not tell us what the error is?  At the very least you should be able to tell us which line, exactly, causes the the program to crash.

Comment: Sorry - I'm very new to all of it. The line that causes it to crash is 'Match match = ssnRegex.Match(txtSSN.Text);', and it gives me something about using the "new" keyword to create an object instance.

Comment: @kfurz: What happens if you initialize the `ssnRegex` right above that line instead of in the `frm..._Load` function?

Comment: @Nija: Yes! That fixed it. Does it have something to do with scope or inheritance? I'm realllly fuzzy on that stuff still.. Also, thank you so much.

Comment: @kfruz: I'd check to make sure that `frmVitalStatistics_Load` is being run. The `ssnRegex` variable wasn't initialized. I haven't worked in winforms for a while, but first thing I'd do is check that the function where it's initialized is being executed.

Comment: @kfurz: Your code is fine. Wherever your problem is, it's not there. There is something else relevant, you are not telling us. http://db.tt/VgC5Zca Please try to grab exception information / stack trace and post it here.

Comment: @kfruz. You're getting a Null Reference Exception. The ssnRegex variable is never actually being instantiated (meaning the variable is null, and does not reference an actual object). Instantiation is done by using the "new" keyword, as you've done in your Load method. However, the form does not automatically link this method to the Load event. This is something you may need to do manually, or have the IDE do for you. Please check to make sure that your Load method has been properly assigned to the Load event of the form to ensure that your ssnRegex is instantiated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the comments and the code it sounds as if you don't have the event handler `frmVitalStatistics_Load` connected to the load event of the form.  This would cause a null pointer exception which would be consistent the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments to the OP, if `frmVitalStatistics_Load` isn't running, it may not be hooked up right as an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to reproduce the error you are seeing with the code you posted. There is likely something in your frmVitalStatistics.Designer.cs file that is different than what I came up with.

As others have said, it could be an event that is missing or perhaps an extra event hooked up that isn't needed.

These are the only events I have hooked up in the form.

```
this.rbMale.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Gender_CheckedChanged);
this.rbFemale.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Gender_CheckedChanged);
this.btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSubmit_Click);
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frmVitalStatistics_Load);
```

Check your frmVitalStatistics.Designer.cs and see if you have any others or if any of these are missing.

One question... Is it freezing AS you are typing or after you click Submit?